# Export blob data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, shell, blob

I have a requirement where I need to read a `CUSTOMER_FILE` file which contains unique customer ids with shell script and export corresponding blob data from an Oracle DB table of each customer into a file. The exported blob data files are again loaded into a different Database.

I have used java to read the file, connect to the database and export the blob data into a file.

This solution works fine when number of customer ids are 0-100. But this leads to performance issues when I have large number of customer ids (say 10000). This will create 10000 files in the server.

Is there any solution to combine all the blob data files into a single file and later split it and use it.

Or any other solution?

Comment: Depends on the method _you_ use to export data.

Comment: Its a normal blob fetch from database and writing it as a binary file

Comment: Why do you even need these intermediary files? Perhaps you can load the BLOB data directly to the target database, without writing anything to files? Absent that, where exactly is the problem? If it's the file system not being able to cope with that many files within the same folder, divide the files to multiple folders (and possibly sub-folders etc.). Also, do you need to create all these files together, or you can get away with one-by-one?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic I cannot load the data directly into the target database. The load has to happen through an intermediate file. That is the restriction :( If the number of records in the file are 10 million then I have to create 10 million files and tar and extract them in the target database server. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Did you measure the performance? Where exactly is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, could you write each blob/file into a tar/zip archive, the result being 1 tar/zip archive containing all the blobs. Of course, when you come to extrac, if extracting all will be a problem, you can restrict the extract to particular file(s).

Comment: Thats right. But what if the number of records are 10 million. That takes a lot of time. Is it a good idea to extract few files and process them? Is there any better solution

Comment: With Java, you can try a multi threaded approach where each thread processes separate data sets. Make the degree of parellelism/threads and the data ranges for each thread parameterised so you can experiment to find the optimal setting.